# download songs from website using json or jsoup

Tags: android

I want to buil a media player  app in android studio
which can download songs from websites through API or using Jsoup
help me, please!
thank a lot!

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is not designed to download contents because its the parser but you can do one thing because there is one method that can get content in bytes then convert that bytes to any type according to your need

```
byte[] bytes = Jsoup.connect("your song url here").ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes();
```

and use following function to store above byte array as song file lolz

```
public void writeFile(byte[] data, String fileName) throws IOException
{
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  out.write(data);
  out.close();
}
```

i have not tested the code since testing is not friendly with me hope it will solve your problem